# PC lags while Running Flutter Application

Tags: flutter, dart

My Pc gets really really slow down and it lags too much whenever I run my flutter application. It freezes the screen completely then I have to restart it or to keep it alive I continuously do some activity on it or keep moving the mouse cursor otherwise If I kept it ideal then it will freeze the screen and everything on the computer get lags.

**My PC Specs**

Ryzen 5 3500

8GB Ram

4GB Graphic Card

Can anyone please provide a solution for it so that my PC will not lag while running flutter application

Comment: Try running flutter app on real device instead of emulator

Comment: Are you running in an emulator ?

Comment: No, I am running on my mobile device through USB But still it lags